# Zlib unzipping javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to unzip, but in every way I get this error.. incorrect header check..

I am trying to decompress this: https://stealthy.glitch.me/evals/nVEWYr.html

```
let res = await require('node-fetch')(new URL(`https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/objects.inv`));
let buffer = await res.body.read();
let bufferstring = buffer.toString().slice(123);

function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    return arrayBuffer;
}
let arrayBuffer = toArrayBuffer(new Buffer.from(buffer));
return zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, 4), (a,b)=>{console.log(a.toString())})
```

Comment: That file is likely not a valid archive then.  I have seen that error on corrupted files as well.

Comment: I don't think thats the issue